# Can't access flutter.dev (Mac OS)

Tags: flutter

I just can't access `flutter.dev`. Yes, I have an internet connection. I guess is due to the `.dev` extension. In Firefox I get **Unable to connect** and a **404** in Safari. Again, my internet connection is fine and I'm able to surf the web with no problem. Any idea?

[image]

EDIT: Don't have antivirus, cache cleaned, set up a custom DNS, router rebooted and still does not work.

Comment: Just checked on Firefox (MacOS) and it's working for me. Retry and see if you still have the problem?

Comment: You can find fixes to common issues if you Google "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED chrome" (or similar with your browser). Things like clearing cache, resetting router etc. If you've tried those out and none worked for you, please mention those in the question.

Comment: Works fine. `.dev` is quite new - it was `flutter.io` before, if it helps

Comment: `.dev` is a valid top level domain, owned by Google. The only unusual thing about it is that it is included in the HSTS listed hardcoded into multiple browsers so all requests have to be secure. (And you can register your own second level domain under it.)

Comment: for me also at home network its working fine but in office network its not working showing error on all browsers (IE,chrome,firefox) as - Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue

Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to flutter.dev because this website requires a secure connection.

Comment: You should open an issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I just solved this problem using this command:

- Go to /etc/resolver folder
- Remove file called **dev**
- done

Which was generated by puma-dev. When I deleted it, it just worked.

Reference:
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2228098?hl=en

Comment: Yoohoo, it worked! Thank you so very much, this thing was driving me crazy. I did so many things and at the end I just gave up on it.

Comment: This also worked for me after many trials in the last 2 months

Comment: What to do if I don't wish to delete the dev file, being used by my other projects?

Comment: i havent tried for that, if u use for another project @abhinav

Comment: I don't have any /etc/resolver folder. You can check out [the list of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX01Y.jpg) in /etc folder. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Thank you so much!. I was wondering why it was not opening in my mac! Never thought There can be such issue.

Comment: were you able to solve the issue @Abdugani_T

Comment: I have the same issue i don't have /etc/resolver folder

Answer (score 2):

Open Network Utility on your Mac, and select the Traceroute tab.  Type Flutter.dev in the top empty box, then select Trace.  If the first trace entry shows 127.0.0.1, you likely have proxy software, like POW, redirecting that path internally.

The Network Utility is **not** in System Preferences > Network.
Use `Spotlight search` to find the `Network Utility`.

Comment: I have OS X El Capitan, I went to System Preferences/Network and there is no Traceroute tag. Same if I click in the Advanced button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue on Windows 10, you can check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64740426/10068879)

Answer (score 0):

A simple router restart or switching to another internet service provider solves it for me anytime it happens.

Answer (score 0):

If the dev file (or resolver folder) is not available in `/etc/`, you could find `resolv.conf` directly inside `/etc`. Then, back up the file as as follows and enter the root password:

```
sudo mv resolv.conf resolv.conf_bak
```

Answer (score -1):

install [KProxy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kproxy-extension/gdocgbfmddcfnlnpmnghmjicjognhonm?hl=en) browser extension and turn it on any time you experience such, this should solve it.