# flutter.dev not working on Google Chrome browser (Windows 10)

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, windows-10

I am trying to visit [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/) on the chrome browser but it says the site can't be reached.

[image]

I tried to visit it using my smartphone and the site is working fine.

What might be causing this issue on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with chrome but with the router settings, you can use a VPN and it will work fine on Chrome but this is a temporary solution. To fix it you need to change some settings in your Network Settings.

1. Go to `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`

[image: Network Connections]

2. Right click on Wi-Fi and select `Properties`
3. In the Wi-Fi Properties windows, go to `Networking` section, double click on `Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)`
4. In the Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) window, click on `Advanced...`

[image: Blog Image]

5. In the Advanced TCP/IP Settings windows, go to `DNS` section and select `Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes`, under it tick the option `Append parent suffixes of the primary DNS suffix` and press OK.

[image: Advanced Window]

6. Close Chrome and restart your PC, the issue is fixed.

Reference: https://sufi.io/linux-etcresolv-conf-equivalent-in-windows-8-to-add-domain-suffixes/

If you are facing the same issue on Mac OS, you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375467/cant-access-flutter-dev-mac-os)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this same issue. I modified my `hosts` file by adding the IP address of flutter.dev and domain name. Then I can access the flutter website using chrome. Because before modifying the `hosts` file, when I ping to flutter.dev it outputs the ping request could not find the host.