# flutter.dev is not working in macbook air

Tags: android, ios, macos, flutter

Im Using Macos Bigsur. unable to access Fluttter.dev tried all these approaches
[Can't access flutter.dev (Mac OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375467/cant-access-flutter-dev-mac-os).

i don't have /etc/resolver  folder.

Comment: Would you provide some screenshots? and preferably, check whether your computer could resolve the host flutter.dev? (e.g. `nslookup` or `ping`)

Comment: @chungonion i got it resolved its problem wiht flutter.dev site it is down.